# Microsoft Access database export to excel/xml with 5 million rows

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, ms-access

I am very new to the Microsoft Access database (table) and trying to convert the Access table to the format I can use as the pandas data frame in Python.

Here is the situation, the database is about 5 million rows and every time I tried to export to excel or XML it was only able to convert the first 1 million rows. I was wondering two things:

1. whether if there exists a format I can export all rows without row limitation?
2. if the above is not possible, then is there a method to break the Access database for every 1 million rows into separate files, and I can export those to different excel/xml files (copy to clipboard would exceed the limit here)?

Any thought is welcome!

[Update]: export to txt file works for me and can do 10 million records. The way to avoid generating converting error is to use the comma "," as the seperator. Thanks all!

Comment: Perhaps CSV????

Comment: You can't have more than 1M rows in an Excel file, period. When Excel uses PowerPivot it *can* load more than 1M rows but these are stored in a columnstore format, similar to what Analysis Services uses. None of the Excel generating libraries can do the same. And none of the Excel-reading programs can read it either

Comment: `if there exists a format I can export all rows without row limitation?`there are a *lot* of such formats, built for far more data than any Access DB could handle. CSV or text in general is the simplest. HDF5, Arrow and more allow storing millions of records and easily retrieving them, something that can't be done with a text/csv file. You can check all the `to_` methods in the Pandas docs for options

Comment: PS: Pandas can also zip CSV and other files, and read directly from ZIP. Excel itself is a ZIP package containing XML files. If you save your data as `.csv.gz` or `.zip`, Pandas will automatically compress it while saving. It will also decompress it automatically when reading

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks! would you mind letting me know how to export to .zip or .csv file? I was trying to export to .txt earlier but it runs into https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/cant-export-access-table-to-text-file/024228c8-4ead-4e21-a553-09b459a33fb7 this error, and I still couldn't get it fixed. Would it affect saving in .csv or .zip file?

Comment: Edit your quest to show attempted code and error message or start a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in access, you should be able to export that table to csv, and not try to export to excel. I don't believe that the .csv (text) export has a limit.

From access, ctrl-g (jumps to command line/debug window), and then type in this:

```
 docmd.TransferText acExportDelim,,"LContactHistory","c:\test\mybig.csv", True
```

So, the above should export the file. However, Access often will 'freeze' up when you do the above - but it is worth a try. (above seems ok for about 1 million rows).

Next up?

Read the table row by row, output to a text file. This tends to be the best for REALLY big files. and the bonus points are that the VERY old legacy code in VBA for file output operations goes back to the DOS days - they are STUPID FAST high performance.

the other advantage of a loop, is you can give access (and the UI message pump) a gulp of air so to speak - this is what tends to freeze up anyway.

So, do this in native access + VBA code - it will work the best.

This code will work:

```
Sub OutPutBig()

    Dim strOutFile          As String
    Dim intOutFile          As Integer
    Dim strMyTable          As String
    Dim rstData             As DAO.Recordset
    Dim Counter             As Long
    Dim CounterUp           As Long      ' value to update progress
    
    CounterUp = 20000      ' update display every 20,000
    Counter = 0
    
    strMyTable = "LContactHistory"
    strOutFile = "c:\test\big.csv"
    
    intOutFile = FreeFile
    
    Open strOutFile For Output As #intOutFile
    
    Set rstData = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strMyTable)
    
    Dim sOutline As String
    
    ' output first row of field names
    sOutline = ""
    Dim fField As DAO.Field
    For Each fField In rstData.Fields
       If sOutline <> "" Then sOutline = sOutline & ","
       sOutline = sOutline & qu(fField.Name)
    Next
    Print #intOutFile, sOutline
    
        
    Do While rstData.EOF = False
       sOutline = ""
       For Each fField In rstData.Fields
          If sOutline <> "" Then sOutline = sOutline & ","
          sOutline = sOutline & qu(fField.Value)
       Next
       Print #intOutFile, sOutline
       rstData.MoveNext
       
       Counter = Counter + 1
       If Counter Mod CounterUp = 0 Then
           Debug.Print Counter
           DoEvents
       End If
       
    
    Loop
    
    Close (intOutFile)
    rstData.Close
    
    Beep
    Debug.Print "done export - " & Counter
    
     
End Sub

Public Function qu(s As Variant) As String
   
   If IsNull(s) Then
      s = ""
   End If
   
   qu = Chr(34) & s & Chr(34)
   
End Function
```